# Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyModule\Entity\MyEntity::findAll() doctrine orm 2 zf2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am started with doctrine since a few months, and cant not resolve this problem.

well the details

**composser.json**

```
"name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",
  "description" : "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
  "require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework" : "~2.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "0.9.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-module" : "0.9.0",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools" : "0.0.2",
    "bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler" : "v1.1.0"
  },
  "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
  "keywords" : [ "framework", "zf2" ],
  "homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/"
}
```

**application.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'BjyProfiler',
        'Application',
        'Publicacion',
    ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor','./module','./module',
        ),
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
         ),
    ),
);
```

**module.config.php**

```
namespace Publicacion;
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Publicacion\Controller\Publicacion' => 'Publicacion\Controller\PublicacionController',
            'Publicacion\Controller\Categoria' => 'Publicacion\Controller\CategoriaController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'publicacion' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/publicacion',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                        // the controllers for your module are found
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Publicacion\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Publicacion',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                    // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                    // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                    // specific routes.
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),),),

                    'categoria' => array(
                        'type'    => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            // Change this to something specific to your module
                            'route'    => '/categoria',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                                // the controllers for your module are found
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Publicacion\Controller',
                                'controller'    => 'Categoria',
                                'action'        => 'index',
                            ),),),),),),),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'Publicacion' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
        'display_exceptions' => true,
    ),

    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )))));
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Publicacion\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Publicacion\Entity\Publicacion;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class PublicacionController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //var_dump($this->getEntityManager());
        $publicaciones = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Publicacion\Entity
\Publicacion')->findAll(); // <-- HERE 
        return array('publicaciones' => $publicaciones);
    }
}
```

**index.phtml**

```
<table>
<?php
foreach ($publicaciones as $publicacion){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$publicacion->getId()."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$publicacion->getTitulo()."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

The text error is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Publicacion\Entity\Publicacion::findAll() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProyect\module\Publicacion\src\Publicacion\Controller\PublicacionController.php
>   on line 29

The Publicacion Entity

```
namespace Publicacion\Entity;

use Publicacion\Entity\Categoria;
use Publicacion\Entity\Referencia;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl\Column\Boolean;

/**
 * 
 * @author Darwin
 *
 * Publicacion
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="publicacion")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Publicacion\Entity\Publicacion")
 * @Annotation\Name("Publicacion")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods")
 */

class Publicacion
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     * @var int|null
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * 
     * @var string
     */

    private $titulo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */

    private $introduccion;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */

    private $contenido;


    // relación muchos a muchos una referencia puede referenciar a muchas publicaciones y viserversa

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Referencia", inversedBy="publicaciones")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="publicacion_referencia")
     * @var Collection
     */

    private $referencias;

    // relación muchos a muchos, una categoria puede referenciar a muchas publicaciones y viserversa

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categoria", inversedBy="publicaciones")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="publicacion_categoria")
     * @var Collection
     */

    private $categorias;

    //****** MODULO COMENTARIO **********
    // relación uno a muchos ( una publicación puede referenciar muchos comentarios / un comentario solo puede referenciar una publicación o otro comentario)
    /**
     *-ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comentario", mappedBy="publicacion")
     *-var Collection
     */

    //private $comentarios;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime
     */

    private $fechaCreado;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $fechaModificado;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @var Boolean
     */

    private $publicado;

// property methods ....
}

?>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: please include your entity. Especially the EntityRepository annotation.

Comment: included the Publicacion Entity , I think I'm understanding the problem ...

Comment: the problem was the annotation * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Publicacion\Entity\Publicacion") , I'm not using custom repositories and was indicating the same entity as repos ... Now works properly, change the annotation so * @ORM\Entity .Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Bram Gerritsen, with your comment I could see the error, the problem was the annotation

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Publicacion\Entity\Publicacion")
```

, I'm not using custom repositories and was indicating the same entity as repos ... Now works properly, change the annotation so

```
* @ORM\Entity
```

Thank you very much for your help!